# Access denied when using File.Copy

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, file-copying, system.io.file

after few days of searching and investigating the problem, I finnaly decided to ask the question over here.
In the beginning I want to apologize for my english, it's not so well as it should be, so hope, you'll understand the question well :).

I have a problem when using File.Copy in ASP.NET to summarize the problem - it always says, that I don't have the permission to access the folder defined in "pathFrom". (the only way how the code works is, when I run it in my Visual Studio in debugger), after I upload it on web server, it stops working.

CODE:

```cs
protected void buttonclick(object sender, Eventargs e){
string pathFrom = "\\\\sqlSRV\\folder1\\thisOne.txt";
string pathTo = "\\\\webSRV\\folder2\\overHere.txt";

string directory = "\\\\sqlSRV\\folder2";
if (Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(pathFrom, pathTo, true);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Lab0.Text = "Not found.";
    }
    catch (FileLoadException)
    {
        Lab0.Text = "Cant open.";
    }
}
```

- The servers are in the same domain.
- Shared folders does have ALL permissions for `sqlSRV$` and `webSRV$`, `NETWORK SERVICE`, `IIS_WPG` even for group `Everyone` (just for testing right now)
- we don't want to use impersonate and write the username and password into the code due to security
- everything is on our LAN
- running IIS10

In the old days we had similiar function in ActiveX, where it all worked (because it knew which user was running the code).

Can anyone, please, help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What user is your app pool running as in IIS? I know you have said you have allowed access to everyone, but have you tried specifying full access for the specific user the web app is running as (even for testing purposes).

Comment: If I get it right, we run it under: Built-in acc: ApplicationPoolIdentity.If I don't, can you, please, tell me where to find it? Thx :)

Comment: Open IIS, expand the Sites folder, find your application -> right click -> Manage Website -> Advanced Settings. This dialog should have an Application Pool option which will confirm what app pool your application is running in.

If you now open open the Application Pools option (above sites) it will list out all the app pools. Find your app pool and the Identity column is the user your app pool is running as, and therefor that is the user the web app is using to try and access the file/folder.

Comment: So I was right - we run it under ApplicationPoolIdentity (one of built-in accounts). After your post, we tested all the built-in options (localsystem, localservice, network service, applicationpoolidentity). Even when we tested it as a TestUser (on domain) it also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show the full exception that gets thrown?

Comment: @IanSoc Sorry to reply too late, I was off site. The full exception is over here: [link](https://www.muruda.cz/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/errFileCopy.png)